# Antipode of a quasi-Hopf algebra is assumed to be bijective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

I have found two different definitions of a quasi-Hopf algebra $H$: The first one assumes that there is an anti-endomorphism of H (called antipode) with certain properties and the other one assumes the antipode to be bijective.

Is there a reason for those different definitions? What is the more usual one?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but rather some thoughts on a quite similar problem, related to the definition of quasitriangular hopf algebras:
There are actually two variants of the definition of "quasitriangularity" (and more generally of the notion of "almost-cocommutativity") met in the relevant literature: Some authors (see for example [Kassel's](https://archive.org/stream/springer_10.1007-978-1-4612-0783-2/10.1007-978-1-4612-0783-2#page/n0/mode/2up) book, ch. VIII, XIII or [Montgomery's](http://bookstore.ams.org/cbms-82) book, ch.10) include in the definition of quasitriangularity  the requirement for bijectivity of the antipode, whereas other authors (see for example [Majid's](http://www.cambridge.org/gr/academic/subjects/physics/theoretical-physics-and-mathematical-physics/foundations-quantum-group-theory?format=PB&isbn=9780521648684#QavFKbAB4HWt6SdX.97) book, p.40, prop.2.1.8) prove that it is not necessary and bijectivity can be proved to be a consequence of the rest of the defining axioms.

So, i was wondering whether there might be a similar situation here. Since I am not a specialist in quasi-Hopf algebras i cannot say more. In any case it would be helpfull if you provided direct citations to the couple of definitions you are talking about.

Comment: That's interesting! But Kassel does not assume the antipode to be bijective in the braided=quasi-triangularity case. But he take Hopf algebras with bijective antipode in most of his Propositions.

Comment: I gave a look at Kassel's book. In p. 173 he lays the definition of quasi-cocommutativity without the assumption for the bijectivity of the antipode. But later in the same page (se definition VIII.2.2) he lays the definition of braided (=quasitriangular) hopf algebra including the assumption of the invertibility of the antipode. This was the definition i had in mind.

Comment: In any case what book (or article) are you reading?

Comment: I am reading the books of Kassel and Chari & Pressley, both with title Quantum Groups. You are right, a quasi-cocommutative Hopf algebra is not assumed to have a bijective antipode, but a braided one is. At least it is part of the data, he does not mention it with words.

Comment: Returned the favor twice ;)